# Is it impossible to paginate filtered results with the Weaviate vector DB?

Tags: pagination, weaviate, vector-database

## Query Filter Works

Using Weaviate's query filtering works fine, e.g. from [their tutorial](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/search/filters):

```py
response = (
    client.query
    .get("JeopardyQuestion", ["question", "answer", "round"])
    .with_where({
        "path": ["round"],
        "operator": "Equal",
        "valueText": "Double Jeopardy!"
    })
    .with_limit(20)
    .do()
)
```

## Pagination Explodes?

But grabbing the first 20 results is not useful for a full-featured semantic search feature.  We need pagination to grab the next 20 results, and the next 20, and so on.  [Weaviate uses query cursors to do this](https://weaviate-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/weaviate.gql.html#weaviate.gql.get.GetBuilder.with_after), where a record's UUID is provided:

```py
response = (
    client.query
    .get("JeopardyQuestion", ["question", "answer", "round"])
    .with_where({
        "path": ["round"],
        "operator": "Equal",
        "valueText": "Double Jeopardy!"
    })
    .with_after("6726aaa8-818b-49dc-8fea-9bc646ddfed6")   # <-- ID cursor pagination
    .with_limit(20)
    .do()
)
```

But this throws an error:

> `where cannot be set with after and limit parameters`

The error comes from [this line of Weaviate code](https://github.com/weaviate/weaviate/blob/624abccb7c38ef5d37cf7b05b3fe6c6e4ba4bfd9/entities/filters/cursor_validator.go#L38), and the `with_after()` docs say it "requires limit to be set but **cannot be combined with any other filters or search.**"

So we can't combine filters, cursors, and limit parameters like this.

What is the correct way to do filtered query pagination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can paginate using the [`with_limit()`](https://weaviate-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/weaviate.gql.html#weaviate.gql.get.GetBuilder.with_limit) and [`with_offset()`](https://weaviate-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/weaviate.gql.html#weaviate.gql.get.GetBuilder.with_offset) methods together.

For example, let's say you have 10 records in the DB for a given `SomeClass` class, and you would like to retrieve the first 5 records with one query, and the next 5 with a following query.

First query:

```py
client.query.get("SomeClass", "someProp").with_offset(0).with_limit(5).do()
```

Second query:

```py
client.query.get("SomeClass", "someProp").with_offset(5).with_limit(5).do()
```

Comment: Oh awesome, thank you.  I wonder what the `with_after(cursor)` method is even for?  

Comment: @kdbanman with_after is used for deep pagination! By default, using offset/limit, you can only retrieve up to 10K objects, cursor allows you to fetch more (in case you want to reindex for instance).

Comment: That seems arbitrary.  Why do users need to use a different ID and pagination API  just to get more records?